# Cloud services that provide continuous integration and delivery

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, google-compute-engine, continuous-deployment

Anyone know of some good cloud services that provide continuous integration and delivery with deployment to cloud providers like AWS or GCE? We use Jenkinks and want to integrate it with a cloud service so we can rapidly deploy applications to dev, test instances on AWS and GCE.

Comment: By "good cloud service that provides continuous integration" - you mean a **hosted** continuous integration / delivery solution, which itself is a service and you can automate the testing and deploying process **with this service** to a cloud platform like AWS/GCE?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud services don't provide 'services' in general. They provide the infrastructure where you can build the services on top of.

It's quite easy to deploy to AWS instances with Jenkins/Bamboo/etc.

Answer (score 1):

for a full end to end CI & CD "in the cloud" you can try

codeship (https://www.codeship.io/)

circleci (https://circleci.com/)

travis CI (https://travis-ci.com/)

But your sourcecode will probably need to be hosted on github or bitbucket not on your local infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good overview on different hosted continuous delivery services at this [Quora answer](http://www.quora.com/Continuous-Integration-CI/What-is-the-best-continuous-integration-deployment-server)

Full Disclosure I'm one of the founders of Codeship